# Updating from kernel 3.16 to 3.17 broke device support

Tags: arch-linux

I have a wacom bamboo pad, one of the non-supported tablets by the wacom project. When you first plug it in the kernel doesn't seem to recognise it at all. Despite of that, I could make it work by adding this line to the kernel command line parameters:

```
usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0318:0x40000000
```

After further investigation I've come to the conclusion that this is setting the NO_IGNORE flag to the linux kernel for my device, as I could find in the following macro declaration

```
#define HID_QUIRK_NO_IGNORE                     0x40000000
```

Anyway, the thing is that during an update (actually a full wipe/reinstall) of my root partition because of unrelated problems, my linux kernel updated from 3.16 to 3.17, and now the tablet is completely unrecognized by the kernel. Not even writing to any of the /dev/input/ files. Note that this is the same behaviour that I got before adding the usbhid.quirks line on my boot commands. I, of course, have that line on the kernel parameters, and it shows up in /proc/cmdline. Removing it didn't change a thing.

I have to say that the only thing that's detecting the tablet is lsusb and that it's using a usbhid driver, but somehow it doesn't get to the part where it outputs data to the xserver or /dev/input...

After looking at the package versions and realising the only relevant thing that changed was the kernel I downgraded to 3.16.3 kernel and everything worked again just fine, so I'm guessing this is what's causing the issue.

What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a bug report to the Linux kernel and talked to the maintainer of the usb hid driver.

There has been a huge rework with the Wacom evdev driver and my device ended up being unrecognised.

The owner of that code told me he'll have a look into it, so I guess it's going to get fixed sometime soon (maybe next version?), for the time being I'll just use the old kernel whenever I need to use my tablet.